# Is it possible to exclude a specific subdirectory from a podman volume mount?

Tags: containers, podman

For example, let's say you have a directory dir/ with an arbitrary number of subdirectories including dir/subdir/, and you want to mount dir/ to a podman container with every subdirectory also mounted except dir/subdir/.

Is this possible in podman? If so, is it possible to do this purely with the arguments of a podman run command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not possible, the entire folder will be available inside the container.

You can overcome this with permissions, acl or even symbolic links. In the last case, create a second folder with links pointing to only the folders you want to be available inside the container.

Comment: I tried `podman run --rm -v ./dir:/dir:Z -v ./emptydir:/dir/subdir:Z docker.io/library/alpine ls /dir/subdir` . Mounting the empty directory _./emptydir_ inside the first mount seems to hide the _dir/subdir_. It seems to work... Maybe there is some caveat I don't see?

Comment: I don't understood, you mounted `./emptydir` inside `/dir/subdir`, the content in `/dir/subdir` in the container, will be the content of `./emptydir` in your host machine.

Comment: I wrote an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75499491/757777 and added an example

Answer (score 1):

Use an extra bind-mount to hide the directory **dir/subdir/**

In other words, first bind-mount **dir/** and then  bind-mount an empty directory over **dir/subdir** to hide its contents.

```
$ mkdir dir
$ mkdir dir/subdir
$ mkdir dir/subdir2
$ mkdir emptydir
$ touch dir/subdir/file1.txt
$ touch dir/subdir2/file2.txt
$ podman pull -q docker.io/library/fedora
b2aa39c304c27b96c1fef0c06bee651ac9241d49c4fe34381cab8453f9a89c7d
$ podman run --rm \
         -v ./dir:/dir:Z \
         -v ./emptydir:/dir/subdir:Z \
         docker.io/library/fedora find /dir
/dir
/dir/subdir
/dir/subdir2
/dir/subdir2/file2.txt
```

In the output from the command `find /dir` there is no file **dir/subdir/file1.txt**

Comment: In fact, this is a nice trick!